# Sequelize - Destroy Records with Many to Many Relationship and Through Table

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a scenario where I am trying to delete a record from a table with a many-to-many relationship, as well as the matching recordId within the junction (through) table that connects my two tables. I know there are `set` and `get` methods to create a record for one table and then automatically create the relationship in the `through` table, but is there a way to `delete`?

Here is the relationship:

**User**

```
User.belongsToMany(db.Organization, { through: 'organization_member', foreignKey: 'user_id'})
```

**Organization**

```
Organization.belongsToMany(db.User, { through: 'organization_member', foreignKey: 'organization_id'})
```

Note both foreignKey's are aliased to camel case by Sequelize which is why the error message is different than the column mentioned in the association.

And I'm trying to use a destroy command on the `user` table where any user is associated to the organization associated with the current users session. Unfortunately, the following command doesn't work because `organization_id` doesn't exist on the `user` table, but the `organization_member` junction table. Can anyone help?

```
deleteUsers: function(organizationId, t){
        console.log("Step 10: Delete Users");
        //DELETE users
        return models.User.destroy({
            where: {
                organizationId: organizationId
            }
        },{ transaction: t })
    }
```

**Error:**

```
{ [SequelizeDatabaseError: column "organizationId" does not exist]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems

1) you're trying to delete users by organization id, but your users don't have an `organization_id` column, the `organization_member` table has that column. Are you trying to remove the association of user and organization, or are you trying to remove the user?

2) You are fighting Sequelize on column names. I think your best bet is to configure Sequelize to just use underscores or camel case for all foreign keys. That way you won't have to worry about always over-ruling it.

Here's my config:

```
 const db = module.exports = new Sequelize(url, {
   dialect: 'postgres',

   define: {
     underscored: true,       // use snake_case rather than camelCase column names
     freezeTableName: true,   // don't change table names from the one specified
     timestamps: true,        // automatically include timestamp columns
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

1) Both. I'm trying to remove the association, then those users a part of the removed association. This method is a part of a larger chain of actions to delete an account from my application.

2) Good call.